# catkin_make src failing

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am currently having a weird problem. My package cannot be found anymore even though it was working before.
I put the package *larah* in the *src* folder and the workspace setup is correct. I also sourced the *devel/setup.bash*.
**roscd larah** does not find the package either and **rospack profile** didn't help.

**catkin_make** seems to be working fine:

```
 Base path: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/install

Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build"
Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build"

[  5%] Built target openni_camera_gencfg
[ 10%] Built target fallen_person_wrapper
[ 73%] Built target openni_driver
[ 78%] Built target fallen_person_detector
[ 84%] Built target image_saver
[ 89%] [ 94%] Built target openni_node
Built target localization_node
[100%] Built target openni_nodelet
```

But **catkin_make src** gives me following output:

```
Base path: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/install

Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build"
Running command: "make src -j4 -l4" in "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build"

make: *** No rule to make target `src'.  Stop.
Invoking "make src -j4 -l4" failed
```

also: **ROS_PACKAGE_PATH** gives the correct location of my package...

Any ideas??

Thank you!

Salocin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241931/catkin_make-src-failing/) by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, the problem vanished the same way as it came. I did not do anything except putting an alias in the bashrc like this:

```
alias cat_make='cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin_make && source devel/setup.bash'
```

this is exactly what I did a million times already... opened up a new shell, ran **cat_make** and suddenly my package could be found again...

Strange.

---

Originally posted by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) with karma: 33 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0